# from xml to arraylist by xstream

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I want to read data from XML to ArrayList by xstream.

I can read only one Object with this code:

```
List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("Event", Event.class);
FileInputStream fis = null;

try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    events.add((Event) xstream.fromXML(fis));
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
     try {
         fis.close();
     } catch(IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }  
}
```

How can I get next Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an Event instance from "fromXML" method. Try to get the list of events using this method.
So you need to update alias to retrieve list/collection of events and cast result of "fromXML" method to this collection.
It will be possible only if your XML assumes the list/collection of events (if it assumes just Event, I think you will get an error).